# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString double my string

Tags: objective-c, ios7, replace, nsstring, xcode5

Simple code that doesn't work.

### Edit:

**This code work on my iPhone 4 but doesn't work on my iPad Air?.?**

```
NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," withString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
```

Console Log:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... your code and your logs look completely unrelated. Are you just copying/pasting from your code or have you altered it for SO? It's best just to do a copy paste.

Comment: I just copy & paste, why don't you think so? :)

Comment: Well... the string starts out as "1" and then you do stuff to it using ",," and then it ends out being "11". There's no way that a "1" could be mistaken for a ",".

Comment: What about staring with `NSString *text = textField.text` and then forget about the `textField` and use only `text` for debugging?

Comment: I end up with make it universal and make a storyboard for iPad, it's just totally works like normal. (I have the storyboard for iPad originally, but I changed the project to iPhone only so I could test the iPhone version on my iPad, I hope the problems isn't come form there.)

Comment: Also, my Xcode iOS SDK version is 7.1 but my iDevices is all iOS 7.0.x. Thanks all.